# Deleting record in SQL depending on next record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have records with columns: `ID`, `Time_End` and `Attribute`.

I need to delete all records,

```
WHERE Time_End = '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND Attribute <> '9'
```

but only:

- if the next row does not have the same attribute number

**or**

- the next row has the same attribute number and a `Time_End` value of `1990-01-01 00:00:00.000`

For example:

```
ID     Time_End                     Attribute
---------------------------------------------
235    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      5                  /delete
236    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      5                  /delete
237    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      5
238    2016-10-10 23:45:40.000      5


ID     Time_End                     Attribute
---------------------------------------------
312    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      8                  /delete
313    2016-01-09 18:00:00.000      6                  
314    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      4                  /delete
315    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      7
316    2016-10-10 23:45:40.000      7
```

Our customer have 50 database tables with thousands of records in every table (and of course more columns, I mentioned only those, which have impact on solution). Records are send in to the database from PLC, but sometimes (we don't know why) PLC send also wrong records.

So what I need is a query which finds those wrong records and deletes them. :)

Anybody who knows how the SQL code should look like?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL server

Comment: yes I am using, MS SQL

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh213125.aspx `Lead` function in SQL? It could help.

Comment: @Darshan_Viswanath_BI `LEAD()` function is suppported from sql-server 2012 only. You have to first ask the version and then give your suggestion.

Comment: @Viki888 it was a suggestion. There are no tags to suggest the SQL server version OP using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my SQL below. First, we collect ids to delete using two window functions (LEAD) to get the next row needed data. Then, with all needed data computed, apply the evaluation rules proposed by the OP. Last, use the obtained ids to delete the affected records of the tablet by id with an in clause.

```
 DELETE toDeleteTable 
 WHERE toDeleteTable.id IN (WITH dataSet
                              AS (SELECT toDeleteTable.id,
                                         toDeleteTable.time_end, 
                                         toDeleteTable.attribute, 
                                         LEAD(toDeleteTable.time_end,1,0)  OVER (ORDER BY toDeleteTable.id) AS next_time_end,
                                         LEAD(toDeleteTable.attribute,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY toDeleteTable.id) AS next_attribute
                                    FROM toDeleteTable)
                            SELECT dataSet.id
                              FROM dataSet
                             WHERE dataSet.time_end = '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
                               AND dataSet.attribute <> '9' 
                               AND (  (dataSet.next_attribute = dataSet.attribute AND dataSet.next_time_end  = '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000')   
                                    OR dataSet.next_attribute <> dataSet.attribute)
                           )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To make sure it's as helpful as possible, please add some explanation to show how you've solved the OP's problem.

Comment: First, collect ids to delete using two window functions (LEAD) to get the next row needed data.  Then, with all needed data computed, apply the evaluation rules proposed by the OP. Last, use the obtained ids to delete the affected records of the tablet by id with an in clause.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Time_End ORDER BY ID DESC) AS seq
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Attribute <> '9'
      AND Time_End = CAST('1990-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
)
DELETE FROM t
WHERE seq > 1;
```

Not Tested - HTH ;).

Comment: This does not take into account the full set of requirements for what to delete: "if record in next row have not same Attribute number _or record in next row have same Attribute number and Time_End = '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'_"

Comment: Exactly, it delete more records than it should :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a simple `apply` join.  The below should give you enough to make this work for your needs without doing anything complex:

```
declare @t table(ID int
                ,Time_End datetime
                ,Attribute int
                );
insert into @t values(235,'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000',5),(236,'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000',5),(237,'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000',5),(238,'2016-10-10 23:45:40.000',5),(312,'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000',8),(313,'2016-01-09 18:00:00.000',6),(314,'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000',4),(315,'1990-01-01 00:00:00.000',7),(316,'2016-10-10 23:45:40.000',7);

select t.*
        ,tm.*
from @t t
    outer apply (select top 1 tt.Time_End
                            ,tt.Attribute
                    from @t tt
                    where t.ID < tt.ID
                    order by tt.ID
                    ) tm
where t.Attribute <> tm.Attribute
    or (t.Attribute = tm.Attribute
        and tm.Time_End = '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'
        );
```