# Self join table current row and next row horizontally in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am implementing a functionality wherein I have to delete current row based on values present in next row of same table.

I have records with columns: `id`, `created_at` and `mark`.

I need delete all records,

```
WHERE currentrow.mark != nextrow.mark or (currentrow.mark = nextrow.mark and currentrow.created_at= '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

i.e. only records with next rows have not same mark or records with next row have same mark and `created_at = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'`

```
id      created_at                  mark
235    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      5                  /delete
236    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      5                  /delete
237    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      5
238    2016-10-10 23:45:40.000      5


id       created_at                 mark
312    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      8                  /delete
313    2016-01-09 18:00:00.000      6                  
314    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      4                  /delete
315    1990-01-01 00:00:00.000      7
316    2016-10-10 23:45:40.000      7
```

Kindly help to retrieve table every row joined next rows of same table horizontally in result set.

Comment: The condition you've specified for records to delete and the values in your example data are 10 years out. Which is it?

Comment: I can see the same sample data in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485396/deleting-record-in-sql-depending-on-next-record?noredirect=1#comment70176721_41485396. But that is tagged to `sql-server`

Comment: @Viki888 thats some question you won't see often. And if so, at least twice a day? :D

Comment: @Cataklysim For your kind information, I just pointed out since both people may be from same company working on same scenario. If so, one people can delete his or her question.

Comment: Chances are some of the solutions suggested on the existing question will work (or at least with some minor modifications) on Mysql too

Comment: As per your question, "only if record in next row have not same mark", why not id 313 not cancelled?

Comment: could we say that you just want to delete duplicates `WHERE created_at= '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand the delete conditions completely. But I will give answer to your last question 
**"Kindly help to retrieve table every row joined next rows of same table horizontally in result set."**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT (@rowid1 := @rowid1 + 1) firstSeq, id firsttableid, created_at firsttablecreated_at, mark firsttablemark FROM `mytable`
JOIN (SELECT @rowid1 := 0) a) table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT (@rowid2 := @rowid2 + 1) secondSeq, id secondtableid, created_at secondtablecreated_at, mark secondtablemark FROM `mytable`
JOIN (SELECT @rowid2 := 0) a) table2 ON table1.firstSeq = table2.secondSeq - 1 and **(your conditions)**
```

This will give you the result set as you need. Now you may add your required conditions to convert to delete

Comment: @SatishakumarAwati Take the inner queries separately, execute and see the output. You may get it.!! All the best

Answer (score 5):

One way to join the next row is

```
INNER JOIN `tablename` AS `next` ON `next`.`id` = (
  SELECT MIN(id) FROM `tablename` WHERE `tablename`.`id` > `current`.`id`
)
AND (`next`.`mark` != `current`.`mark` 
  OR `next`.`created_at` = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000') // maybe 1990?
```

Comment: This worked !! Without condition.
SELECT * from tablename a INNER JOIN tablename AS `next` ON `next`.`id` = (
  SELECT MIN(id) FROM `tablename` WHERE `tablename`.`id` > `a`.`id`
);